# Creating XLSX (Excel) spreadsheet (or Zip files) in Javacript Server Side

Tags: javascript, excel, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I'm looking for some guidance or ideas on how to create a proper formatted Excel (XLSX) spreadsheet using Javascript **Serverside**.

I've found multiple sites/libraries (such as SheetJS) which can create the file, but depend on web functions (ie. blobs and the like).

Alternatively a JS library which similarly can create a zip file without using blobs/web functions (ie. i can create the XML files structured within the XLSX file/zip but cannot compress server side.

The reason for this is the need to export these files on Server Side scripts within NetSuite/SuiteScript... so far I've come up empty.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get what you are looking for using the 'N/file' SuiteScript module.  Create a file using file.Type.EXCEL

Comment: Appreciate the answer, however file.type.EXCEL is an XML spreadsheet renamed to XLS extension, not a proper XLSX document.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a scheduled script code sample that will take saved search results and create an excel file that is saved to the file cabinet.  You can reference Suite [Answer Id 93557](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/93557/kw/93557).  Also the "file.Type" enum does allow for the type Zip, reference [Suite Answer Id 43530](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/43530)

```
define(['N/search','N/file'], function(search, file) { 
  function execute(scriptContext){
    //Load saved search
    var mySearch = search.load({id: '47'});

    //Run saved search
    var mySearchResultSet = mySearch.run();

    //Headers of CSV File separated by commas and ends with a new line (\r\n)
    var csvFile = 'Internal ID,Item Name,Average Cost\r\n';

    //Iterate through each result
    mySearchResultSet.each(iterator);

    function iterator(resultObject){
      //get values
        var internalid = resultObject.getValue(mySearch.columns[0])
        var itemid = resultObject.getValue(mySearch.columns[1])
        var formulacolumn = resultObject.getValue(mySearch.columns[2])

        //Add each result as a new line on CSV
        csvFile += internalid+','+itemid+','+formulacolumn+'\r\n'
        return true;
    }

    //Variable for datetime
    var date = new Date();

    //Creation of file
    var fileObj = file.create({
        name: 'Saved Search Result - ' + date.toLocaleDateString() +'.xlsx',
        fileType: file.Type.EXCEL,
        contents: csvFile,
        description: 'This is a CSV file.',
        encoding: file.Encoding.UTF8,
        folder: 123
    });

    //Save the CSV file
    var fileId = fileObj.save();
  }
    return {
        execute: execute
    };
    
});
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer, however file.type.EXCEL is an XML spreadsheet renamed to XLS extension, not a proper XLSX document.